# Indirect variables in PHP 7

Tags: php, php-7

I have a code which takes javascript from database and render it for particular page. In javascript are used substitutions for php variables which should be replaced by actual value of php variable. Substitutions look like `{{_GET.page}}` should be replaced by value of `$_GET['page']`

for PHP 5.6 i am using following code and all works good

```
if(isset($adminpage['js']) && $adminpage['js'] != ''){
    preg_match_all('#\{{(.*?)\}}#', $adminpage['js'], $match);
    foreach($match[1] AS $k => $m){
        $m = explode('.', $match[1][$k]);
        if(isset($m[1])){
            $match[1][$k] = ${$m[0]}[$m[1]];
        }else{
            $match[1][$k] = $$m[0];
        }
        $adminpage['js'] = str_replace($match[0][$k],$match[1][$k],$adminpage['js']);
    }
    $jsfiles[] = '
<script type="text/javascript">'
.$adminpage['js'].
'</script>';
}
```

But it does not work in PHP 7.
Does anyone know what how to change it and explain pls? Thanks

Comment: So this is a PHP script to convert your PHP scripts?

Comment: yes this is php code which replace those things with value of php variable and after that render javascript

Comment: You have a typo `$match[1]$k]` should be `$match[1][$k]`

Comment: Tried it and still does not work

Comment: What errors are you getting then?

Comment: PHP Notice: Array to string conversion followed by  PHP Notice: Undefined variable: Array

Answer (score 0):

Just found out what was the problem :)

```
if(isset($m[1])){
    $match[1][$k] = ${$m[0]}[$m[1]];
}else{
    $match[1][$k] = ${$m[0]};
}
```

Curly Braces in second case was missing.
Strange because in PHP 7 should be curly braces changed to normal braces according to this:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php